# Jumping to a specific record in a parent form (MS-Access form / VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access form `Form1` with a button that opens `Form2`.  `Form2` is not a subform. `Form2` has a number of text controls that are unbounded.  There is a button called `Commit`.

When it is clicked, it takes the values in the unbounded controls and inserts them into various tables. One of these is inserted into the source table as `Member_Id`.

Once the values are inserted, the following is supposed to happen:

1. Focus is set on `Form1`.
2. The Form1 Current record is set to the Member_Id that was inserted into its data source table.
3. Form2 closes leaving Form1 with the focus displaying the Member_Id record previously inserted.

I am able to do the record insertion, **but I can't close `Form2`**. Would anyone have an idea of what I need to do?

```
Sub Commit_Record_and_Close()
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '' Insert values including Member_Id into source table HERE.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Forms("Form1").SetFocus
    Set rst = Forms("Form1").RecordsetClone
    strCriteria = "[Member_Id] = " & CStr(lng_Member_Id) 'ember_Id previously set.
    rst.FindFirst strCriteria
    Forms("Form1").Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    Forms("Form1").Requery
    Forms("Form1").Controls("cbo_Selector").Requery 'drop down that contains Member_Id

    ' The following 2 lines were inserted in desparation because I couldn't get Form1 to requery.
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acDesign
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acNormal, , strCriteria
    Me.SetFocus ' Form2
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Caption, acSavePrompt ' Form2
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your requery working and it's just the close you're having issues with? what code IS working?

Comment: So, you already know how to find the correct record with the `OpenForm` method... just use the same criteria with **[the `DoCmd.FindRecord` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-findrecord-method-access)**.

Answer (score 0):

To make the search/goto record work, you need to **first** requery the form and control, **then** search and goto. Otherwise the search can't find the new record.

```
Forms("Form1").Requery
Forms("Form1").Controls("cbo_Selector").Requery 'drop down that contains Member_Id

Set rst = Forms("Form1").RecordsetClone
strCriteria = "[Member_Id] = " & CStr(lng_Member_Id) 'ember_Id previously set.
rst.FindFirst strCriteria
Forms("Form1").Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
```

To make the Close work, you need the form **name** instead of its caption.

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSavePrompt ' Form2
```

If the order of events is

- Form1 opens Form2
- Form2 closes itself

then you don't need any `.SetFocus`. Form1 will automatically get the focus back when Form2 closes.